# Chart.js - Fill Text only appearing when hovering over one part of the doughnut

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am working with Chart.js and have an issue that I need some help with.

The doughnut is created correctly and shows the information I need, however, its only showing the filltext value when I hover over one aspect of the chart.

this is the code I am working with

```
options = {
    cutoutPercentage: 75,
    rotation: Math.PI,
    //circumference: Math.PI * values[0],
    //segmentShowStroke: false,
    animation: {
        animateScale: true,
        onComplete: function () {
            var width = this.chart.width,
                height = this.chart.height;

            var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
            this.chart.ctx.font = fontSize + "em Verdana";
            this.chart.ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

            var text = "82%",
                textX = Math.round((width - this.chart.ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
                textY = height / 2;
            console.log(RpData);
            this.chart.ctx.fillText(RpData.datasets[0].data[0] + "%", textX, textY);
        }
    },

    legend: {
        display: false,
    },
    tooltips: {
        enabled: false,
    },

};

$('#riskFactorChartLoading').hide("fast");
var ctx = $("#riskFactorChart").get(0).getContext("2d");

var riskFactorChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: RpData,
    options: options
});
```

which appears like this;

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is to see the result of the mouse hover without having to hover the mouse over it to see my values.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide full code of yours. As "RpData" is not given....in the code.

Here is the jsfiddle link which working fine, but as you are not given any link to full snippet or code we can't check what the issue is...

[`Chart JS snippet - (dkrvl2011)`](https://jsfiddle.net/dkrvl2011/wnd3n0t9/)

Comment: is there any working example where the label doesnt blink on mouseover? i get that this happens because the label is rendered on the onComplete Animation - but if it is a multitude of labels, it is really not looking nice. and enabling tooltips is mostly also not an option, though it seems to get rid of the animation and therefor the blinking - https://jsfiddle.net/ds8r2apg/